# How to decrypt android adopted storage without the key?

Tags: external-sd, storage, encryption, 8.1-oreo, adoptable-storage

I would like to know if there is any possible workaround for decrypting the adapted storage. I don't care about recovering my data because I've got the backup already. I tried formatting the sd card several times from the custom recovery as well as from the pc with no luck. Since I've already formatted /data partiton of my phone, I got no way to recover my lost key. So is there any way to make the sd card usable?

Comment: You don't have to decrypt an SD-card to make it usable again. Once you have deleted all data there is nothing left that can be decrypted. Just delete the entire partition and may be the first sectors of the disc (not the partition) to make sure that the sd-card can no longer be recognized.

Comment: From diskpart to ease US partition master, I tried everything. Ease US partition master gives this error ---> "There are some errors occured while writing partition chains on disk". Windows tells there is some problem in my disk. When I try to fix it, it says unable to fix.

Comment: That sounds more like a defect SD-card. Windows diskpart tool does not care about Android encryption.

Comment: If it were a defective SD card then why would it still get detected on windows. Also, EaseUS partition master shows, there are 2 partitions on the disk.

Comment: Because flash memory often starts to fail on write operations while read operations still work. So a defect sd-card behaves often like a read-only memory system.

Comment: repartition MicroSD Card from PC card reader with gparted or diskmgmt.msc